# Date returned by resultset.getString was wrong at some time

Tags: java, mysql

I am using MySQL database.Here I have datetime field in my table and in my java code I get the value by using `resultset.getString` method.It works fine but sometimes it returns wrong date or previous date.

Here is my Java code:

```
resultSet.getString("date_of_schedule")
```

it returns `'2015-09-21'` correctly but sometimes it return `'2015-09-20'` as a date.Can Anyone explain me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could be a time zone issue

Comment: Why are you retrieving a datetime field as a string? Fetch it in a more appropriate type, then format it if if you need to. (Admittedly the JDBC API around date/time types isn't great, but...)